# 'extract_doi' is not an exported object from 'namespace:impactr'

Tags: r, metadata, doi

I want to install the package `impactr` from github. Following the guideline stated by the package developer (https://rdrr.io/github/kamclean/impactr/f/vignettes/vignette_2_extract.Rmd), I repeatedly get the following error.

```
devtools::install_github("kamclean/impactr")
my_dois <- c("10.1111/j.1365-2486.2008.01617.x","10.1007/s10533-011-9655-2")       
out_doi <- impactr::extract_doi(doi = my_dois, get_impact = TRUE)
Error: 'extract_doi' is not an exported object from 'namespace:impactr'
```

What is the problem? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are there any warnings/errors from the command `devtools::install_github("kamclean/impactr")`? Have you tried restarting R and loading the impactr library with `library(impactr)` before running the commands?

Comment: I've tried the `library(impactr)`. But there is a warning error like `Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\lucp10632\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK-impactr\impactr\libs\x64\impactr.dll to C:\Users\lucp10632\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\impactr\libs\x64\impactr.dll: Permission denied`.

Comment: Sounds to me like it didn't install properly. Perhaps try uninstalling the package, then installing using the [remotes package](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes) (i.e. `remotes::install_github("kamclean/impactr")` and/or raise an issue on github (https://github.com/kamclean/impactr/issues)